# Display simple product SKU for configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, sku

How can I include the simple product sku to display for configurable products which have more than two or more drop down options ( two or more attributes)?  I would like the SKU to display after all the selections have been made for the configurable drop downs. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Was the answer I gave of any use to you?

Answer (score 7):

Mapping the attribute options in the dropdowns to actual products can be done by using the `spConfig` javascript variable printed on the product view page of every configurable product.

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config({
"attributes":{
   "502":{
      "id":"502",
      "code":"shoe_size",
      "label":"Shoe Size",
      "options":[{
         "id":"46",
         "label":"3",
         "price":"0",
         "oldPrice":"0",
         "products":["32"]
      },{
         "id":"45",
         [...]
      }]
    }},
[...]});
```

Notice the `products` keys that have an array of product ids. Using some javascript that observes the `onchange` event of your option dropdowns you should be able to work your way through the array ending up with the product the user has chosen.

Now for mapping that to the product SKU, you're probably best of retrieving them from a custom javascript array which you can create by using the code from [this article](http://www.tripleginteractive.com/blog/magento/magento-configurable-products-simple-product-data/). So now for some untested code

```
$simple_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct(Mage::registry('current_product'))
                            ->getUsedProductCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                            ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

$id_to_sku = array();                           
foreach ($simple_collection  as $_item)
{
    $id_to_sku['p'+$_item->getId()] = $_item->getSku();
}   

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var confIdToSku = '.json_encode($id_to_sku).';
</script>';
```

Which would output an array like

```
var confIdToSku = {"p32":"pr-sku-1", "p35":"pr-sku-2"}
```

That would enable you to map the product ID to the SKU you need.

I'd suggest creating a new PHTML file for this in your template directory, using block type `core/template` and calling that in the `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`.

I'm no hero with Javascript so I didn't include any javascript code examples in my answer, I hope you can figure that part out for yourself.

Comment: This is fantastic, is there a way to ensure that it grabs a product simple sku that is IN STOCK?  @Sander mangel

Comment: I don't have the rep to edit this answer, but there is a typo in the example. It should read `$id_to_sku['p'.$_item->getId()] = $_item->getSku();`. Otherwise great answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this post to get all details of selected simple product of configurable product.
You can get Id, sku, name etc... using this post.

[Get Simple product details of configurable products like ID,SKU,Product Name](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.in/2014/03/get-simple-product-details-of.html)