# Magento 2 - Why do SKU not change dynamically in configurable product view page

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1, sku

When you change an attribute in a configurable product the product image changes dynamically but the SKU doesn't change.

Also, if you add a configured product to your basket it gives you the image of the configurable product (and not of the simple product) which could be very confusion for customers.

Is there any fix for this issue(s)?

Comment: you have to customize for that its own, its default functionality to show only change image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display simple product SKU for configurable products](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/display-simple-product-sku-for-configurable-products)

Comment: The answer to "why" is "because that's how it's implemented". Magento does not use any attributes of the simple products besides images and the configurable attributes to display the configurable product. In the linked duplicate there's a possible approach to add this feature to Magento 1. I retracted my close vote because I realized you asked for Magento 2.1 - the code will be different but the general approach will be similar.

Comment: For Magento 1 we have Better Configurable Products, does anybody know if there is such an FOSS extension for Magento 2 ?

Comment: test on 2.2.3, not work, i don't understand what happened
maybe it's the problem of my theme

Comment: Solved!! finally i have used this module and its work perfectly for me. let me if its help you too https://codecanyon.net/item/magento-2-dynamic-configurable-product/22813380

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did that once for Magento 2.0, don't have the code available but can show you where you need to make changes:

- Write a Plugin for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` and add the SKUs to the result:

  ```
  $config['skus'] = [];
  foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
      $config['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
  }
  ```
- Extend `Product.Config` from `app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/view/adminhtml/web/js/configurable.js` using RequireJS. A good place to add the code to change the displayed SKU is `reloadPrice()`. You will have access to the SKUs via `this.config.skus`

Comment: I am surprised these is not an event dispatched in the `getJsonConfig` function..

Comment: @StevieG I think in Magento 1 there was an event, but in Magento 2 plugins are preferred over events, so events that can be replaced with a plugin are removed gradually.

Comment: Oh no, I used an observer for this same function with bundled products `catalog_product_option_price_configuration_after`...I fear it may be removed

Answer (score 33):

I wrote the module based on Fabian Schmengler's solution. 
This works for me on Magento 2.1.3.

`/app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'YourVendor_YourModule/js/model/skuswitch': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`/app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/web/js/model/skuswitch.js`

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function(targetModule){

        var reloadPrice = targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice;
        var reloadPriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(reloadPrice, function(original){
            //do extra stuff

            //call original method
            var result = original();

            //do extra stuff
            var simpleSku = this.options.spConfig.skus[this.simpleProduct];

            if(simpleSku != '') {
                $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);
            }


            //return original value
            return result;
        });

        targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice = reloadPriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

`/app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Plugin/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php`

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type;

class Configurable
{

    public function afterGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        $jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);

        $jsonResult['skus'] = [];
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
            $jsonResult['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
        }


        $result = json_encode($jsonResult);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

`/app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="YourVendor_YourModule_Plugin_Magento_ConfigurableProduct_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable" sortOrder="10" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Feedback is appreciated! I got this by trial&error based on http://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/

Comment: thanks a lot. Saved me a bit of time. But I had to change the name and location on require-config.js to /app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Comment: @TNordkvist You are right, my mistake! Fixed in the answer.

Comment: A small addition and now it works on swatches as well https://github.com/netrixab/magento2-configurable-sku-switch

Comment: Works on 2.1.9, I'm to magento and this has saved me lots of time

Comment: If parent product doesn't have description then how to display our simple product description based on selection ?

Answer (score 1):

Works great on Magento 2.2.1.  For those who are new to Magento Module Development, you have to create few more files before follow @nbjohan's tutorial.

Create
app/code/[vendor-name]/[module-name]/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="[Vendor]_[Module]" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
```

app/code/[vendor-name]/[module-name]/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'[Vendor]_[Module]',
__DIR__
);
```

Upgrade on server using:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, the *images* and the *price* will change. **But not SKU.**

More information about which elements on the page change when options are selected can be found here: `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()`.

In order to display the SKU of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing `SKU` for each simple product.

Switching `SKU` when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made free `VCT Change SKU Dynamically` module that solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following code work for me you can try it.

app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Extension_Plugin_ConfigurableProduct_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"/>
    </type>
 
    <type name="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Extension_ConfigurableSkuSwitch_Plugin_Magento_Swatches_Block_Product_Renderer_Configurable" sortOrder="10" type=" Vendor \ Extension \Plugin\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type;
 
class Configurable
{
 
    public function afterGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        $result
    ) {
 
    $jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);
    $jsonResult['skus'] = [];
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
            $jsonResult['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
    }
    $result = json_encode($jsonResult);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer;
 
class Configurable
{
    public function afterGetJsonConfig(\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable $subject, $result) {
 
        $jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);
        $jsonResult['skus'] = [];
 
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
           $jsonResult['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
        }
        $result = json_encode($jsonResult);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Vendor_Extension/js/model/skuswitch': true
            },
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Vendor_Extension/js/model/swatch-skuswitch': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\web\js\model\skuswitch.js

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
 
    return function(targetModule){
 
        var reloadPrice = targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice;
        var reloadPriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(reloadPrice, function(original){
        var result = original();
        var simpleSku = this.options.spConfig.skus[this.simpleProduct];
 
            if(simpleSku != '') {
                $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);
            }
            return result;
        });
        targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice = reloadPriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\web\js\model\swatch-skuswitch.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
 
    return function(targetModule){
        var updatePrice = targetModule.prototype._UpdatePrice;
        targetModule.prototype.configurableSku = $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html();
        var updatePriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(updatePrice, function(original){
            var allSelected = true;
            for(var i = 0; i<this.options.jsonConfig.attributes.length;i++){
                if (!$('div.product-info-main .product-options-wrapper .swatch-attribute.' + this.options.jsonConfig.attributes[i].code).attr('option-selected')){
                    allSelected = false;
                }
            }
            var simpleSku = this.configurableSku;
            if (allSelected){
                var products = this._CalcProducts();
                simpleSku = this.options.jsonConfig.skus[products.slice().shift()];
            }
            $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);
              return original();
        });
 
        targetModule.prototype._UpdatePrice = updatePriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This does not appear to be working for me on Version 2.2.2.  Can anyone assist me?  Been trying for days.

app/code/D4tools/AttributeSkuChanger/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="D4tools_AttributeSkuChanger_Plugin_Magento_ConfigurableProduct_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable" sortOrder="10" type="D4tools\AttributeSkuChanger\Plugin\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/D4tools/AttributeSkuChanger/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="D4tools_AttributeSkuChanger" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>.
</config>
```

app/code/D4tools/AttributeSkuChanger/Plugin/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

```
<?php
namespace D4tools\AttributeSkuChanger\Plugin\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type;

class Configurable
{

    public function afterGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        $jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);

        $jsonResult['skus'] = [];
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
            $jsonResult['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
        }


        $result = json_encode($jsonResult);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

app/code/D4tools/AttributeSkuChanger/view/frontend/web/js/model/skuswitch.js

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function(targetModule){

        var reloadPrice = targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice;
        var reloadPriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(reloadPrice, function(original){
            //do extra stuff

            //call original method
            var result = original();

            //do extra stuff
            var simpleSku = this.options.spConfig.skus[this.simpleProduct];

            if(simpleSku != '') {
                $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);
            }


            //return original value
            return result;          
        });

        targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice = reloadPriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

app/code/D4tools/AttributeSkuChanger/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
    var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'D4tools_AttributeSkuChanger/js/model/skuswitch': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -3):

How to get this one to work in Magento 2.2.6 foldernames and placement.

I downloaded this one:
This works for me on Magento 2.2.5,
https://github.com/andreecz/magento2-configurable-dynamic

And placed it like this app/code/Andering/ConfigurableDynamic

And added

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku" data-dynamic="sku"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

to my theme in catalog_product_view.phtml

Comment: I am having issues on 2.2.6 as well, it works on 2.2.5 though. Did you figure this out?

Comment: Without a working link, the answer is of little use.