# Dynamically update SKU of configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, sku

I have a configurable product with many options.
How can I update the sku based on selected options?
I have followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130128/magento-2-why-do-sku-not-change-dynamically-in-configurable-product-view-page/130148) answer, but I am stuck at the JavaScript part.
I try to get the `this.config.skus`, but I can't find out how.

Could someone provide a working example?
I am using Magento 2.1.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing in 2.1 and cannot find a solution

Comment: Isn't that Magento 2 standard? Is there something like Better Configurable Products for Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, *images*, *price*, etc will change, but **not SKU.**

In order to display the SKU of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing `SKU` for each simple product.

Switching `SKU` when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made free `VCT Change SKU Dynamically` module that solve this problem.

Comment: Not able to install vct/changeskudynamically module using composer

Comment: What error occurs?