# Mixin for Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable::_reloadPrice not working

Tags: configurable-product, widget, dynamic, mixins

I'm trying to follow the example here

[Magento 2 - Why do SKU not change dynamically in configurable product view page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130128/magento-2-why-do-sku-not-change-dynamically-in-configurable-product-view-page)

to create a mixin for configurable products that will show dynamically a notification when the user selects an option that changes the price.

My task is very similar to the original post where the sku is changed but I haven't been able to make that example work or achieve what I'm trying to do.

I'm putting the relevant parts of the code here.

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/configurable-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
    return function (targetModule) {

        //code here is executed
        var reloadPriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice, function (original) {

            //code in here never gets executed
            //call original method
            var result = original();

            //custom code to show a notification
            console.log('test');

            //return original value
            return result;
        });

        targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice = reloadPriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

`requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/configurable-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My mixin seems to be loaded in the page, but I don't see any part of the code inside the wrapped function execute at all and it seems targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice is undefined during the whole process which I assume is the reason it fails.

What could cause this issue?

I'm on Magento 2.3.1

Comment: var reloadPrice = targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice; define and try

Comment: var reloadPrice is also undefined after var reloadPrice = targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice and the result is the same as before.

Comment: I discovered it, another mixin was not returning the correct result that's why the variable targetModule was not defined correctly.