# Change the display of attributes when the customer changes the product configuration

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute, frontend, magento2.3.1

I will try to be as clear as possible.
On the configurable products pages, when the customer chooses his product configuration, the price display changes according to the price of the configuration.

So far, everything is normal.

However, I will use the SKU as an example.

When changing the configuration, the SKU display does not change.  It always displays the SKU of the configurable product, not the SKU of the declination or configuration.

How can Magento make this change?
Which file manages this update of data to be displayed?

Thank you in advance!

Florian

Magento Version: 2.3.1 CE

EDIT: I don't know why, but Stackexchange refuses me "Hello all," at the beginning of my post. Sorry for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 - Why do SKU not change dynamically in configurable product view page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130128/magento-2-why-do-sku-not-change-dynamically-in-configurable-product-view-page)

Comment: @BartZalas , You're right ! I don't fond it before ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @BartZalas Finaly no ! This solution don't work for Magento 2.3.1. 
Tried to modify it by different way, and nothing to do. :(

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the SKU of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing **SKU** for each simple product. Out of the box, when choosing options, *images*, *price*, etc will change, but **not SKU.**

The **SKU** obtained with `getJsonConfig()` can be updated in the frontend when selecting an option in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` or/and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements) (*Dropdown*, *Visual Swatch*, *Text Swatch*).

---

I made `VCT Product Info Switcher` module that solve this problem.